# Move div to bottom of parent

Tags: html, css

So I have this html

```
<div class="search-form">
  //other divs
  <input type="text" class="submit"/>
</div>
```

The search-form is the height of the page. I want the submit to be in the search form, but at the bottom of the page. I've tried using position fixed, and set the width to 30%(like the search form), but when I'm on a larger screen, the submit button becomes larger than the search form.

How do I make the submit button go to the bottom of the search form?

Comment: Have you tried using `vertical-align: bottom;` for that css class? Or setting your text input & submit button to `display: block;`?

Comment: @Ty, you would think that would work, but vertical-align is more about aligning text and images.

Comment: It can't be used to align form elements? I've never really tried to use it for that purpose but I have used it to align items within a table

Answer (score 2):

Apply the following:

```
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
```

Then make changes as needed:

```
height: Xpx;
width...
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

If the form has absolute, relative (the usual choice), or fixed position, then you should be able to set the input to absolute position and set its bottom coordinate to 0.

Is fixed position what you want? Bottom of the window or bottom of the form?